# WordPress Users API throwing 403 Forbidden error

Tags: php, wordpress, http-status-code-403, wordpress-rest-api

I have an personal website in WordPress, recently I upgrade my WordPress version to 6.2.2.

Its decoupled site, frontend in react & WordPress rest API I am using to populate post on my site.

After upgrading to 6.2.2 User API stopped working & throwing 403 forbidden error.

I am using Application Password to login & generate my JWT Token using `JWT Authentication for WP-API` plugin.

All other API's where login required, those are working fine apart from user API `(/wp-json/wp/v2/users/1)`.

I don't have any firewall installed as of now, I have only light speed plugin enabled.

I tried with disabling all the plugins but still no luck.

After dig down to core WP I found below code where WP is looking for role wise permission, if anyone know about it please help me.

```
/**
 * Permissions check for getting all users.
 *
 * @since 4.7.0
 *
 * @param WP_REST_Request $request Full details about the request.
 * @return true|WP_Error True if the request has read access, otherwise WP_Error object.
 */
public function get_items_permissions_check( $request ) {
    // Check if roles is specified in GET request and if user can list users.
    if ( ! empty( $request['roles'] ) && ! current_user_can( 'list_users' ) ) {
        return new WP_Error(
            'rest_user_cannot_view',
            __( 'Sorry, you are not allowed to filter users by role.' ),
            array( 'status' => rest_authorization_required_code() )
        );
    }

    // Check if capabilities is specified in GET request and if user can list users.
    if ( ! empty( $request['capabilities'] ) && ! current_user_can( 'list_users' ) ) {
        return new WP_Error(
            'rest_user_cannot_view',
            __( 'Sorry, you are not allowed to filter users by capability.' ),
            array( 'status' => rest_authorization_required_code() )
        );
    }

    if ( 'edit' === $request['context'] && ! current_user_can( 'list_users' ) ) {
        return new WP_Error(
            'rest_forbidden_context',
            __( 'Sorry, you are not allowed to list users.' ),
            array( 'status' => rest_authorization_required_code() )
        );
    }

    if ( in_array( $request['orderby'], array( 'email', 'registered_date' ), true ) && ! current_user_can( 'list_users' ) ) {
        return new WP_Error(
            'rest_forbidden_orderby',
            __( 'Sorry, you are not allowed to order users by this parameter.' ),
            array( 'status' => rest_authorization_required_code() )
        );
    }

    if ( 'authors' === $request['who'] ) {
        $types = get_post_types( array( 'show_in_rest' => true ), 'objects' );

        foreach ( $types as $type ) {
            if ( post_type_supports( $type->name, 'author' )
                && current_user_can( $type->cap->edit_posts ) ) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return new WP_Error(
            'rest_forbidden_who',
            __( 'Sorry, you are not allowed to query users by this parameter.' ),
            array( 'status' => rest_authorization_required_code() )
        );
    }

    return true;
}
```